# Application ID's for existing NFC reader infrastructure

Tags: android, nfc, contactless-smartcard, emv

I read through the Android docs which say that the application IDs (AIDs) for existing NFC reader infrastructures like for VISA and MASTERCARD are publicly known and registered, but I could not find them anywhere on the web.

If anyone has found them, can you please share the application ID's for these publicly known NFC readers?

I am looking to emulate a card that can be tapped on an NFC terminal for VISA, MASTERCARD.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Google to find these application IDs? I guess not. Try [this](http://bit.ly/1hzDRkr).

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EMV) lists, for instance:

- A0000000031010 (VISA credit/debit)
- A0000000041010 (MasterCard credit/debit)

Note that there is several others too. You might also want to start by reading the EMV specifications for contactless payment cards (get them from [EMVCo](http://www.emvco.com)).